# How to display post ranges instead of page numbers in Wordpress pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

How to output posts range contained in each step of pagination instead of just current page number ?

I mean:
1-10 11-20 21-30 31-40... 101-110 Next

instead of :
1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 10 Next

My current pagination function:

```
function wp_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '<span class="next">Next</i>' : '<span class="previous">Prev</span >';
    $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '<span class="previous">Prev</i>' : '<span class="next">Next</span >';
    $big = 999999999; 

    if( $total > 1 )  {

         if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )

             $current_page = 1;

         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {

             $format = 'page/%#%/';

         } else {

             $format = '&paged=%#%';

         }

        echo paginate_links(array(

            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => $format,
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $total,
            'mid_size'      => 3,
            'type'          => 'list',
            'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
            'next_text'     => $next_arrow,

         ) );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `paginate_links` function does not allow you to change the format of displayed page numbers.

Source of `paginate_links` function: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2742

Following line is responsible to build page numbers:

```
$page_links[] = "<a class='page-numbers' href='" . esc_url( apply_filters( 'paginate_links', $link ) ) . "'>" . $args['before_page_number'] . number_format_i18n( $n ) . $args['after_page_number'] . "</a>";
```

As you can see, the page number simply inserted as content of the `<a>` tag without any possibility to change displayed format - `number_format_i18n( $n )`

To achieve your goal, you should create your own implementation of this function. Use the original wp `paginate_links` function as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i figured it out in a different way.
It is possible to output pagination html as array ('type'   => 'array' in paginate_links() options ). I replaced link text for each array element with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a way to achieve this. This is how I did it:

```
$links = paginate_links( array(
   'base'         => esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
   'format'       => '',
   'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
   'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
   'prev_next'    => false,
   'end_size'     => 4,
   'mid_size'     => 4,
   'type'         => 'array',

 ));

 $i = 0;
 $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

 foreach( $links as $link ){        

    $startrange = $i + 1;
    $endrange = $i + 10;

    // is active ?
    if($links[$current_page-1] == $link){
        echo preg_replace('/<span(.+?)>.+?<\/span>/i',"<span$1>$startrange - $endrange</span>",$link);
    }else{
        echo preg_replace('/<a(.+?)>.+?<\/a>/i',"<a$1>$startrange - $endrange </a>",$link);
    }


    $i += 10;

 }
```